# Sql delete parent from child/delete whole tree

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-delete, cascading-deletes

Delete parent and child in loop

Table 1 (Parent table)

```
Id  int
```

Table 2 (Relationship table)

```
Id1 int FOREIGN KEY (Id1) REFERENCES Table1 (Id)    
Id2 int FOREIGN KEY (Id2) REFERENCES Table1 (Id)

Id - Id1 one to one or one to zero relationship 
Id - Id2 one to many
```

Data in table 1

```
Id
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Data in table 2

```
Id1 Id2
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   2
6   4
7   4
8   5
9   5
```

So it is like a tree with root as 1

```
1 has two childs 2 and 3
2 has two childs 4 and 5
4 has two childs 6 and 7
5 has two childs  8 and 9
3,6,7,8,9,10 has no child
```

Best possible way to achieve the below mentioned case:

Deleting 1  =>  deletes the complete table2 and table1(except 10 in table 1)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
update table2 set id2 = null;
delete from table1 where id <> 10;
delete from table2;
```

Comment: Real data has thousands of trees and thousands of independent rows. All trees need not be deleted, some trees are to be deleted, it wont work on big data set.
Sorry for 2 comments, i was not able to edit the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `Recursive CTE`

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Id1,
                Id2,
                id2 AS parent
         FROM   Yourtable
         UNION ALL
         SELECT a.Id1,
                a.Id2,
                b.Id2
         FROM   cte a
                JOIN Yourtable b
                  ON a.parent = b.id1)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  parent = 1
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
--DELETE FROM Yourtable
--WHERE  id1 IN (SELECT id1
--             FROM   cte
--             WHERE  parent = 1)
--OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

If the `select` is returning expected results then comment the `select` and un-comment the `Delete`